# Is there any robust open source Content Management Systems for eCommerce with web service Api support?

Tags: web-services, api, content-management-system, e-commerce

Sorry I am newbie to eCommerce...

Is there any robust open source Content Management Systems for eCommerce with web service Api support?

My client want to build a mobile app on top of the eCommerce system.

So I want one with web service Api support.

Any recommendation? Open to any language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrestaShop, one of the most used and respected Ecommerce platforms on the market. It's Free and Open-source. If your client wants to build a mobile app, then PrestaShop's webservices API would be the best.

Any other requirement that you are looking for?

Best,